# Using python to compare two lists. Why Python compares the first number of the first list with all the numbers of the second list?

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop

Here is the mission of the program:

> Write a program, listcomp1.py, that compares two lists of equal length entered by the user. A third list composed of 0's and 1's should be created to keep track of the differences between the lists. A 0 at index i in the differences list indicates that the items at index i in the the two list being compared are the same. A 1 at index i in the differences list indicates that the items at index i in the list being compared are different.

input: two lists entered by the user, one at a time output: a list composed of 0's and 1's showing where items in the two lists being compared are the same or different

```
def main():
    mylist = [5,7,7,8]
    mylist1 = [5,6,7,8]
    return_val = 0
    final_list = [0]
    num1 = mylist1[]
    for num in mylist:
        if num == num1:
            return_val = 0
        else:
            return_val = 1
    final_list.append(return_val)

main()
```

Comment: Hum... this is not PHP, I don't think `mylist1[]` is idiomatic in Python.

Comment: among other issues you need to indent `final_list.append(return_val)` in once.

Answer (score 2):

A much easier and PEP 8 compliant way to do it.

```
def main():
    my_list = [5, 7, 7, 8]
    my_list_1 = [5, 6, 7, 8]
    return [0 if x == y else 1 for x, y in zip(mylist, my_list_1)]


print(main())
```

Plus you might get some extra points for using list comprehensions and ternary operators. ;)

Answer (score 1):

One liner:

```
[ int(i != j) for i,j in zip(mylist, mylist1)]
```

But if you can't figure out why this works, then I still think you are not going to do well in the class.

Comment: Have to use `!=` instead of `==`

Answer (score 0):

Because you've set `num1 = mylist1[]` (I didn't know that was valid Python). You should be keeping track of an index, and using the same index to index both lists.

I.e.:

```
for i in range(len(mylist)):
    if mylist[i] == mylist1[i]:
        # stuff
    else:
        # other stuff
```

Even better, use an enumeration

```
for i, val in enumerate(mylist):
    if val == mylist1[i]:
        # stuff
    else:
        # other stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

I belive you can make it like this:

```
    mylist = [5,7,7,8]
    mylist1 = [5,6,7,8]
    return_val = 0
    final_list = [0]
    num1 = mylist1
    for num,num1 in zip(mylist,mylist1):
        if num == num1:
            return_val = 0
        else:
            return_val = 1
        final_list.append(return_val)

    print final_list
```

Be aware that python is sensible to indentation and therefore in your code     `final_list.append(return_val)` is wrongly placed. Besides you need to iterate both arrays and not only one. so your test `num == num1` does not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
SAME, DIFFERENT = 0, 1

def get_list(prompt, dtype=lambda s:s):
    return [dtype(s) for s in input(prompt).split()]

def main():
    list1 = get_list("Please enter a space-separated list of integers: ", int)
    list2 = get_list("And again: ", int)
    differences = [SAME if a==b else DIFFERENT for a,b in zip(list1, list2)]
    print(differences)

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```